# Does MySQL close cursor if stored procedure encounters an exception?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, cursors, exception

I've seen two different approaches of cursor handling is MySQL stored procedures. Now I'm curious about their stability, due to potential `MYSQLEXCEPTION` risks in stored routines.

Assuming, that `CURSOR` is opened when DBMS raises `MYSQLEXCEPTION` and goes to `EXIT HANDLER` if it is declared...

*Approach #1:*

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `test1`()
BEGIN
DECLARE `EOS` BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;

DECLARE `buffer` INT UNSIGNED;

DECLARE `MyCursor` CURSOR FOR
SELECT
    `id`
FROM
    `MyTable`
LIMIT 50;

DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR MYSQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN
    ROLLBACK;

    SIGNAL SQLSTATE 'ERR0R' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Oops... FATAL ERROR!', MYSQL_ERRNO = 5656;
    END;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET `EOS` = TRUE;

START TRANSACTION;

OPEN `MyCursor`;

cycle: LOOP

    FETCH `MyCursor` INTO `buffer`;

    IF `EOS`
    THEN LEAVE cycle;
    END IF;

    -- INSERTs to another tables, UPDATEs of another tables and DELETEs from to another tables
    -- Section that might throw a MYSQLEXCEPTION

END LOOP cycle;

CLOSE `MyCursor`;

COMMIT;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Note that if `MYSQLEXCEPTION` will be thrown in commented section, then `MyCursor` probably will not be closed. *Or it will be closed and deallocated in this case?*

Somewhere I've seen following...

*Approach #2:*

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `test2`()
BEGIN
DECLARE `EOS` BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;

DECLARE `buffer` INT UNSIGNED;

DECLARE `MyCursor` CURSOR FOR
SELECT
    `id`
FROM
    `MyTable`
LIMIT 50;

DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR MYSQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN
    ROLLBACK;

    CLOSE `MyCursor`; --   <---- is this even needed here ?

    SIGNAL SQLSTATE 'ERR0R' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Oops... FATAL ERROR!', MYSQL_ERRNO = 5858;
    END;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET `EOS` = TRUE;

START TRANSACTION;

OPEN `MyCursor`;

cycle: LOOP

    FETCH `MyCursor` INTO `buffer`;

    IF `EOS`
    THEN LEAVE cycle;
    END IF;

    -- INSERTs to another tables, UPDATEs of another tables and DELETEs from to another tables
    -- Section that might throw a MYSQLEXCEPTION

END LOOP cycle;

CLOSE `MyCursor`;

COMMIT;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

And now I'm a bit confused about `CURSOR` handling.

***Question:*** Which of this approaches is more accurate and reliable? If I'm not closing `CURSOR` in `EXIT HANDLER` will it impact anything? And if it is, *how "**bad**" might be consequences*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use Approach #1:
according to http://www.brainbell.com/tutorials/MySQL/Working_With_Cursors.htm

If you do not explicitly close a cursor, MySQL will close it automatically when the END statement is reached.